# Sorting 2d array into bins and add weights in each bin

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, binning

Suppose I have a series of 2d coordinates `(x, y)`, each corresponding to a weight. After I arrange them into bins (i.e. a little square area), I want to find the sum of the weights that fall into each bin. I used `np.digitize` to find which bins my data falls  into, then I added weights in each bin using a loop. My code is like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=5000) #x variable
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=5000) #y variable
w = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=5000) #weight at each (x,y)

binx = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
biny = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

indx = np.digitize(x, binx)
indy = np.digitize(y, biny)

#initialise empty list
weight = [[0] * len(binx) for _ in range(len(biny))]

for n in range(0, len(x)):
    for i in range(0, len(binx)):
        for j in range(0, len(biny)):
            if indx[n] == binx[i] and indy[n] == biny[j]:
                weight[i][j] =+ w[n]
```

But the first line of the output `weight` is empty, which doesn't make sense. Why does this happen? Is there a more efficient way to do what I want?

Edit: I have a good answer below (one I accepted), but I wonder how it works if I have bins as floats?--> See edited answer

Comment: I've addressed your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with simple indexing. First get the bin number in each direction. You don't need [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) for evenly spaced bins:

```
xbin = (x // 1).astype(int)
ybin = (y // 1).astype(int)
```

Now make an output grid:

```
grid = np.zeros_like(w, shape=(xbin.max() + 1, ybin.max() + 1))
```

Now the trick to getting the addition done correctly with repeated bins is to do it in unbuffered mode. Ufuncs like [`np.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) have a method [`at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) just for this purpose:

```
np.add.at(grid, (xbin, ybin), w)
```

**Appendix**

This approach is completely general for any even-sized bins. Let's say you had

```
x = np.random.uniform(low=-10.0, high=10.0, size=5000)
y = np.random.uniform(low=-7.0, high=12.0, size=5000)

xstep = 0.375
ystep = 0.567
```

Let's say you wanted to compute your bins starting with `x.min()` and `y.min()`. You could use a fixed offset instead, and even apply [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to out-of bounds indices, but that will be left as an exercise for the reader.

```
xbin = ((x - x.min()) // xstep).astype(int)
ybin = ((y - y.min()) // ystep).astype(int)
```

Everything else should be the same as the original simplified case.

When plotting the histogram, your x- and y-axes would be

```
xax = np.linspace(x.min(), x.min() + xstep * xbin.max(), xbin.max() + 1) + 0.5 * xstep
yax = np.linspace(y.min(), y.min() + ystep * ybin.max(), ybin.max() + 1) + 0.5 * ystep
```

I avoided using `np.arange` here to minimize roundoff error.

Comment: Thanks! For the grid, can I do it with float though? I tried to implement it and I got the error: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: @Limona2000. I don't know how you did that. All of the code assumes you are using floats...

Comment: @Limona2000. Perhaps add an update to the question showing what you tried?

Comment: I used the exact code you wrote after the first four lines of my code (from import numpy to the w array) and got rid of the rest of the my original code- but I still got the same error. Not sure what was going on?

Comment: @Limona2000. Gotcha. This is what happens when I don't test my code. See update. Also found another typo.

Comment: Now that makes sense. Cheers!